# Looking for string in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this dynamic array, generate after a submit $_POST.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => lng_criteria_balance
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => lng_type_balance_positive
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => lng_criteria_sex
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => F
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => lng_criteria_note
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => cane
                )

        )

)
```

Array is variable, and it's key also.
I need to search if a specified value exists. I did try this but

```
<?php
 if (in_array('lng_criteria_balance', $args))
 {
   echo 'found!';
 }
 else
 {
   echo 'not found :(';
 }
```

But it prints "not found".
Thank you.

PS I could check with a foreach loop, but I would not use it (for best performance)

Comment: `in_array` searches in just one array not a multidimensional array.

Comment: Is it always in 0-th index? Or it can be on any level in any key?

Comment: For best performance, I think your array should look like: `Array
(
    [lng_criteria_balance] => lng_type_balance_positive,
    [lng_criteria_sex] => F,
    [lng_criteria_note] => cane,
)`. It also simplifies your code that uses it and makes possible the usage of the PHP standard functions [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) a.s.o.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multi-dimension array you need to check it recursively.

Do like this:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Output:

```
echo in_array_r("lng_criteria_balance", $your_array_variable) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because in your array,  there are numeric keys only.
Use foreach to iterate through the subarrays, and search in that.

```
$inArray = false;
foreach ($array as $key => $subarray) {
    if (in_array('needle', $subarray)) {
        $inArray = true;
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this...**

```
<?php
$arr = array(0 => array("id"=>1,"temp"=>"lng_criteria_balance"),
             1 => array("id"=>2,"temp"=>"test"),
             2 => array("id"=>3,"temp"=>"test123")
);
function search_in_array($srchvalue, $array)
{
    if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0)
    {
        $foundkey = array_search($srchvalue, $array);
        if ($foundkey === FALSE)
        {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value)
            {
                if (is_array($value) && count($value) > 0)
                {
                    $foundkey = search_in_array($srchvalue, $value);
                    if ($foundkey != FALSE)
                        return $foundkey;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            return $foundkey;
    }
}
if(!empty(search_in_array('lng_criteria_balance',$arr)))
{
   echo 'found!';
 }
 else
 {
   echo 'not found :(';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function multi_in_array_r($needle, $haystack) {
     if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
          return true;
     }
     foreach($haystack as $element) {
          if(is_array($element) && multi_in_array_r($needle, $element))
               return true;
     }
   return false;
}
```